# How to make a fetch call in Chrome developer tools console using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to make a fetch call `fetch("https://www.test.com")` in chrome dev tools console.

`--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` opens the dev tools. However, I'm not sure if it is possible to navigate to `console` and type `fetch("https://www.test.com")`

```
            chrome_options = Options()
            chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')

            driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options={'verify_ssl': False},
                                      executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type='google-chrome').install(),
                                      chrome_options=chrome_options
                                      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing commands in the Chrome console for the most part is simply executing JavaScript code.
then you could just execute like follows in Selenium:

```
driver.execute_script("fetch('https://www.test.com'")
```

if you needed to see the returned value of a command since you are using headless mode  then it could be something like:

```
print(self.driver.execute_script("fetch('https://www.test.com')"))
```

Comment: I believe the closing bracket is missing. And ```Print``` returns ```None```      ```print(self.driver.execute_script("fetch('https://www.test.com')"))```

Comment: @user3587025, check if it works without headless mode please

Comment: I tried in headless mode ```chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')``` Returns ```None```